# How to check if the target of a link is an iframe

Tags: javascript

See the following example:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == 'A'){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(true){
      console.log('Target is an iframe');
    } else {
      console.log('Target is not an iframe');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="about:blank">1</a>
<a href="about:blank" target="iframe">2</a>
<a href="about:blank" target="not_iframe">3</a>
<iframe name="iframe" src="about:blank" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

I put `if(true)` in there as a placeholder. How do I actually check whether the target of the link that is being clicked on is an iframe or whether it isn't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really easy solution:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == 'A'){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(window.frames[e.target.target]){
      console.log('Target is an iframe');
    } else {
      console.log('Target is not an iframe');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="about:blank">1</a>
<a href="about:blank" target="iframe">2</a>
<a href="about:blank" target="not_iframe">3</a>
<iframe name="iframe" src="about:blank" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check if an `iframe` with that name exists.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == 'A'){
    var target = e.target.target;
    var iFrameExist = document.querySelector(`iframe[name="${target}"]`);
    if(iFrameExist){
      console.log('Target is an iframe');
    } else {
      console.log('Target is not an iframe');
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="about:blank">1</a>
<a href="about:blank" target="iframe">2</a>
<a href="about:blank" target="not_iframe">3</a>
<iframe name="iframe" src="about:blank" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks. How about using the window.frames property instead of a query selector? Also for some reason return false doesn't work when you click the first link so I changed it to e.preventDefault().

Answer (score 0):

I've expanded out your code to do as you wish.  First you should check the `target` member of the clicked on tag, and if it exists you then want to search for elements with that name (not sure why you didn't use ID though).  Finally, you take the found elements, and check if the first one is or isn't an iframe.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName == 'A'){
    e.preventDefault();
    let tag = e.target;
    
    if (tag.target) {
      let found = document.getElementsByName(tag.target);
      
      if (found.length > 0) {
        let potential = found[0];
        
        if (potential.tagName == "IFRAME") {
          console.log("Target is an iframe");
        } else {
          console.log("Target is not an iframe");
        }
      } else {
          console.log("No element with matching name found!");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No target set");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="about:blank">1</a>
<a href="about:blank" target="iframe">2</a>
<a href="about:blank" target="not_iframe">3</a>
<a href="about:blank" target="isdiv">4</a>
<iframe name="iframe" src="about:blank" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<div name="isdiv">

</div>
```

Comment: I see Daniel Beck is going back and forth on whether 'member' or 'attribute' is the correct term to use.  I completely agree, I went with 'member' due to working with the object as a tag at the time but 'target' is most definitely an attribute so make sure you understand that @asker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm pretty sure you are supposed to use target with name and not with id.